# How we can upload image or photos to ejabberd XMPP web server?

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

Here i am using iOS XMPP library (https://github.com/processone/demo-xmpp-ios) for my chat application, can any one help me out for uploading image from this library.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend uploading images to a third party server and then sending the URL via XMPP.

Here's an example using [Backendless](https://backendless.com) which offer 20GB of free file uploads. You would have to also follow the Backendless docs to install their SDK and setup the API keys:

```
[backendless.fileService.permissions grantForAllRoles:fileName operation:FILE_READ];
[backendless.fileService saveFile:fileName content:file response:^(BackendlessFile * file) {

    // We have the url so we can send the message

} error:^(Fault * fault) {
}];
```

Or to a PHP server using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:_url parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:file name:@"upfile" fileName:name mimeType:mimeType];
} error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager
              uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
              progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                  // This is not called back on the main queue.
                  // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      //Update the progress view                           
                      [progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];
                  });
              }
              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                  if (error) {
                  } else {
                      NSString *filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                      // Send message here

                  }
              }];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Then you can add the image and thumbnail URLs and the image dimensions to the XMPP message:

```
    [xmppMessage addBody:imageURL];
    [xmppMessage addAttributeWithName:bMessageImageURL stringValue:imageURL];
    [xmppMessage addAttributeWithName:bMessageThumbnailURL stringValue:thumbnailURL];
    [xmppMessage addAttributeWithName:bMessageImageWidth floatValue:width.floatValue];
    [xmppMessage addAttributeWithName:bMessageImageHeight floatValue:height.floatValue];
```

I'd recommend setting the body to the `imageURL` so that the image could be opened from a standard XMPP client.

When the message is received, you can access the details again as follows:

```
    NSString * imageURL = [[message attributeForName:bMessageImageURL] stringValue];
    NSString * thumbnailURL = [[message attributeForName:bMessageThumbnailURL] stringValue];
    float width = [[[message attributeForName:bMessageImageWidth] stringValue] floatValue];
    float height = [[[message attributeForName:bMessageImageHeight] stringValue] floatValue];
```

You could then display the image using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

I'd also recommend this [ChatSDK](https://github.com/chat-sdk/chat-sdk-ios) which is a full front end messaging interface for iOS. It contains UITableView cells to display image messages. I used it to build an XMPP messenger using [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework).

Comment: Your answer may be right, but the question is tagged "swift", not "objective-c", so this is rather off-topic... :/

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't see that since it wasn't specified in the title. I'll try to provide a Swift version.

Comment: The language should *never* be in the title, actually - its place is in the tags. Always. // Thanks. :)